# Aligning Elements in a CardView Programatically

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a custom form activity that gives all elements their own `CardView`. When I add elements to a `LinearLayout` and add that to the `CardView` it works just fine, but when I try to arrange them in a `RelativeLayout` they don't seem to go where I want them. Here is a picture that shows the bug: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbSII.jpg). The top is the error I'm getting, the bottom is what I'm trying to get it to look like.

Here's my current code:

```
package com.cpjd.roblu.activities;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.cpjd.roblu.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TeamViewer extends Activity {

LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
);

// adapters
LinearLayout layout;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_team_viewer);
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.team_viewer_cards);

    addEditText();
    addEditText();
    addEditText();
    addEditText();
    addBoolean();
}

private void addBoolean() {
    RadioGroup group = new RadioGroup(this);
    RadioButton b = new RadioButton(this);
    b.setText("Yes");
    RadioButton b2 = new RadioButton(this);
    b2.setText("No");
    group.addView(b);
    group.addView(b2);

    TextView t = new TextView(this);
    t.setText("Boolean");

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(getApplicationContext());

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    group.setLayoutParams(params);

    layout.addView(t);
    layout.addView(group);
    addCard(layout);
}

private void addCard(View layout) {
    CardView card = new CardView(getApplicationContext());
    card.setLayoutParams(params);
    card.setRadius(0);
    card.setContentPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
    card.setUseCompatPadding(true);
    card.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    card.setCardElevation(5);
    card.addView(layout);
    this.layout.addView(card);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `LayoutParams` you specified for the `group`, arguments should be flipped (first constructor argument is width, second - height, not the opposite):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
);
```

Otherwise `group` takes full width of the parent and any horizontal alignment doesn't make any sense. Also try to avoid using `getApplicationContext()` when creating the views, because otherwise you get theme from the app, which may differ from the one you are using in `Activity`.

And the last: specify `LayoutParams` for all the views you create in runtime as well. For example, for the `layout`:

```
layout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT))
```

Keep in mind, that `LayoutParams` is mandatory piece of information for every view. If not specified, then view will use the default one.